# Modify variables in a different module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a newbie to python and programming, so this might be easy, but I couldn't find a suitable answer anywhere. I'm trying to do the following. I would like to have a module with a couple of variables in a module that should be modified by my main module.
Additionally it is not clear from the beginning, if the module with the variables and the variable already exists.
At the moment I'm doing the following:

```
# test2.py
import os

# creates module test1
if os.path.isfile('test1.py') and os.path.getsize('test1.py') > 8:
    pass
else:
    txt = open('test1.py','w')
    txt.write('testvar = {}')
    txt.close()

import test1
testvar = test1.testvar
```

My testmodule looks as follows:

```
# test.py
import test2

testvar = test2.testvar
# now modify testvar

txt = open('test1.py','w')
txt.write('testvar = '+repr(testvar))
txt.close()
```

This works, if run test.py in python but it has the drawback, that I need a separate module for any testvar-like variable. I would prefer if I could have a single module with many such variables and use some sort of `test1.testvar.update(entry)`-method to change the variable.
Furthermore, if I create an exe-file using py2exe the application doesn't recognise the testvar-variable. So there is a further problem in this method.
The reason why I want all this is to change the variable during many different runs of the programme.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Please, just stop doing that. Use a normal file to store variables, for example in JSON format, or XML. What you're trying to do is extremely ugly.

Comment: Or [``pickle``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). Remember, python is a purely-interpreted language. There's no real performance benefit from a value being a constant in code vs. being loaded dynamically at runtime. Self-modifying code is just a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @poe123 As I wrote, I had already assumed, that this would be bad. It was just the best I could do. Is there a reason why I should use XML oder JSON instead of *.py? From what I just read the JSON-file would just look the same as the *.py.

Comment: @aruisdante I'll read through this and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use Python to dynamically create new Python code, which you then load into your original program and execute...?

This is a recipe for many kinds of major and minor disasters. Don't do this.

If you need to store data in a persistent way from one run of a program to another, there are many good ways to do it. Python's standard [`shelve` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) is a very easy way to do it. You basically just open a file and immediately start using it like a `dict` object which can store (almost) anything else.

```
import shelve

sh = shelve.open("myshelf")

sh["foo"] = (1,2,3,4)
sh["bar"] = "I like spam"

sh.close()

sh = shelve.open("myshelf")
print sh["foo"]
print sh.keys()
```

**UPDATE:** If you want human-readable output files, try using the widely-used [JSON serialization format](//wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) instead.

- Unlike `shelf`, `json` module requires you to *explicitly* save and restore a dictionary object.
- The JSON format cannot serialize as many data types as `shelf` without extra code. For example, it can serialize `dict`/`list`, but it can't serialize `set` and will change a `tuple` to a `list`.

Same thing using JSON. Notice that the tuple `sh["foo"]` comes back as a list when it gets serialized and deserialized:

```
import json

# Load sh from JSON file or create a new dictionary if it doesn't exist
try:
    sh = json.load( open("storage.json","r") )
except IOError:
    sh = {}

sh["foo"] = (1,2,3,4)
sh["bar"] = "I like spam"

# Save sh to JSON file
json.dump( sh, open("storage.json","w") );

# Reload it
sh = json.load( open("storage.json","r") )

print sh["foo"]
print sh.keys()
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks great. There is just an encoding-issue, meaning I can't open myshelve in a readable form. However everything can be accessed without any problem, so it's at least machine-readable.
The documentation says that the option writeback=True makes everything work slowly. In my case I will have like 5 dict-variables in myshelve each containing a few hundred entries. Would you expect this being an issue already?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; the `shelf` format isn't supposed to be human readable. I don't think writeback would have a significant performance impact with a data set of that size.

Comment: alright. I guess that cause I'm not too experienced so far, I like to control output I create directly so I tried to open the file myshelf which caused an encoding issue. If that's normal behavior I'll be OK with it. When I read and printed the variables in my script everything was fine.

Comment: If you want a human-readable serialization format, try JSON. I added an example of how to do this above. Any human-readable format will have more limitations in terms of what kinds of data structures it can represent, though.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. For the time being I decided to stick with shelve. Within python everythings works nicely now, but it doesn't work in connection with py2exe where I get an ImportError:
    `ImportError: no dbm clone found; tried ['dbhash', 'gdbm', 'dbm', 'dumbdbm']`
I'll do some research on that and be back, when I know whether or not this should be a separate question.

Comment: this last issue is resolved adding `options={"py2exe":{"includes":["dumbdbm"]}}, zipfile = None` into the setup-command.